# Querying relations in loopback doesn't work via Angular SDK

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

I am trying to query a model relation 
I have two models 
1. Workers
2. Skills

Worker hasMany Skills

I can query the api via the explorer 
http://localhost:3000/explorer/#!/Workers/prototype_get_skills
and /api/Worker/:id/Skills url 
and it gives back a list of skills for a give Worker Id

The issue happens when i try to call the Worker.skills() method generated by Angular SDK where i get a 404 Not Found Error

Below is the Angular implementation that i have

```
 angular.module('worker-dashboard').factory('WorkerDashboardSkillService',['Worker',
    function(Worker){
        function getWorkerSkills(worker){
            return  Worker.skills({
                    filter:
                    {
                        where:
                        {
                            "workerId" : worker
                        }
                    }
                },function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }
        function addWorkerSkills(worker,skill){
            return  Worker.skills.create(
                {
                    "skillName": skill.name,
                    //TODO chabge below
                    "skillCategory": skill.name,
                    "workerId": worker
                },function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }

        return{
            getWorkerSkills : getWorkerSkills,
            addWorkerSkills : addWorkerSkills
        }
    }]);
```

I also tried an example loopback-getting-started-intermediate

Which has an example

```
$scope.reviews = Review.find({
filter: {
where: {
publisherId: $rootScope.currentUser.id
},
include: [
'coffeeShop',
'reviewer'
]
}
});
```

However this example is looks like for the belongsTo relation and when i tried modifying it couldn't do it

Edit : Adding Worker.json

```
{
  "name": "Worker",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "workerName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "workerFirstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "workerLastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "isWorkerBlackListed": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "workerBlacklistedByClient": {
      "type": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "skills": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Skills",
      "foreignKey": "workerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Skills.json

```
{
  "name": "Skills",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "skillName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "skillCategory": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "worker": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Worker",
      "foreignKey": ""
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your Worker.json file?

Comment: @jakerella i added both worker.json and skills.json above

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never. I experienced the same trouble today. You just need to add the angular dependency.

```
 angular 
 .module('app')
  //inject all the model you need
  .controller('ListBooksController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Book', 'Collection', 'Author', function($scope,
$state, Book, Collection, Author) {

  $scope.books = Book.find({
  filter: {
    include: [
     'author'
    //put the model you want to retrieve
    ]
  }
  });
  console.log($scope.books);

}])
```

Comment: i didn't need to add Author for this to work, but otherwise it worked great. Thanks.